# Laravel css appear on title tag

Tags: css, laravel

Can anyone tell me why my code is not detectable by laravel?

It appears that laravel detects it as normal text instead of a function where it appears in the title tag.

```
      <link href="{{asset('public/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Here is the image of the error

[entire code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMYqI.png)

[title error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMJDE.png)

Comment: It seems there are missing close double quote on your html head. It's not a Laravel issue any way. It's just your html rendered in wrong structure.

Comment: Can you show your title tag as well?

Comment: what is your view name? The file must have a **.blade.php**  extension.for example `welcome.blade.php`

Comment: Please show the contents of the ‍`head` tag

Comment: Please share your entire html code

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi Yes I did include .blade.php. 

I  just updated my post. You can check it above.

Comment: put it outside the title tag, contents of the Title tag should be your web page title, this is not where you declare your css

Comment: @Ralph519 oh my god. thanks for spotting that out. I was very dumb.

Answer (score 0):

what a fool of me. The link tag should not be in title tag.